# Django can't find project-level css files

Tags: django

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to understand how django deals with static files. I'm working on building a blog website following a tutorial. here is my project layout:

```
-myblog
  -manage.py
  -myblog
    -settings.py
    -urls.py
  -blog
    -views.py
    -urls.py
    -views.py
    -static
      -blog
        -css
          -style.css
    -templates
      -blog
        -blog.html
  -static
    -css
      -style.css
  -templates
    -index.html
```

but the index.html file can't find it's css file, in index.html file, I have

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

but it can find the css file in app directory

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link href="{% static 'blog/css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

my settings.py file:

```
"""
Django settings for myblog project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/


# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'blog/templates'),
    )


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myblog.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myblog.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'myblog',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'q',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'US/Eastern'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/
#
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'blog/static/'),
    )
```

can anyone tell me what's going on here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can have as many static files folders as you want, just a)namespace those folders accordingly (static files for the whole project and for an every app separately) and b) [provide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/) the path to your static folders within `settings` file.

In most up-to-date django (1.8) project I have the following settings

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app_name_here/static/'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/bootstrap-3.3.4'),
)
```

no `STATIC_ROOT` defined.

Comment: I added my settings.py in the post, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @KevinZhu to be able to use [STATIC_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#static-root) you need to `collectstatic` first - thats if you are ready for deployment. Does it work properly if you add `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')` to `STATICFILES_DIRS` ?

Comment: No, it says the `STATICFILES_DIRS` should't contain `STATIC_ROOT`.

Comment: Did django defined `STATIC_ROOT` variable upon `startproject` or you did it manually? See if it works if you put `STATIC_ROOT = None`. Other thing to try, as I mentioned earlier, you can collect your static files by running `django-admin collectstatic`, but i'm pretty sure you will need to do it over and over if your project is in development.

Comment: Django defined `STATIC_ROOT` automatically. It doesn't allow me to change it to None, it says `You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path` and when I do `django collectstatic` it says `unknown command: collectstatic`.

Comment: because its not `django collectstatic` but `django-admin collectstatic`

Comment: oh, sorry, but I did use `django-admin collectstatic` and it complained `unknown command: collectstatic`

Comment: is your `settings` file being loaded at all? Can you show the whole file (hide secret_key)?

Answer (score 0):

Django can't detect the directories out from your project folder. If you keep the static and templates folder in myblog it will work smoothly.

```
-myblog
  -myblog
    -settings.py
    -urls.py
  -blog
    -views.py
    -urls.py
    -views.py
    -static
      -blog
        -css
          -style.css
    -templates
      -blog
        -blog.html
  -static
    -css
      -style.css
  -templates
    -index.html
```

Comment: my fault, the static and templates folders are actually in the project folders (I revised my file structure), but it doesn't work.